# Kendo-UI Datasource is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have hard coded JSON-data in a kendo-ui datasoruce and want to transmit it to a Knockout observableArray. The Problem is toJSON seems to return an empty array which is not obvious to me,cause the JSON is hard-coded inside the data of the dataSource.

```
//The data hard-coded into the js-file
var eventsViewModel = new kendo.data.DataSource({
data:[
{   id:3,
    created:1385573907907,
    priority:1,
    reporter:"Martin",
    category:"MÃ¤hdrescher",
    type:"S690",
    title:"Hangausgleich defekt",
    message:"MÃ¤hdrescher umgekippt",
    status:"offen",
    client:"Bauer",
    field:"Kaiserslautern - Kohlbach",
    scenario:0,
    document:true,
    positionLatitude:49.405703, 
    positionLongitude :7.423623},

{   id:1,
    created:1385739507907,
    priority:3,
    reporter:"T670-4",
    category:"MÃ¤hdrescher",
    type:"T670",
    title:"Hydraulikdruck unter Minimalwert",
    message:"Hydraulikdruck unter 200 bar",
    status:"offen", 
    client:"Meyer", 
    field:"Homburg - Auf der HÃ¶h",
    scenario:0, 
    document :false, 
    positionLatitude:49.342852,
    positionLongitude:6.824287},
{   id:2,
    created:1385656707907,
    priority:2,
    reporter:"Anna",
    category:"Traktor",
    type:"9560RT",
    title:"Kette gerissen",
    message:"Linke Kette gerissen",
    status:"offen",
    client:"Schulze",
    field:"Kaiserslautern - Feldstraße",
    scenario:0, 
    document:false, 
    positionLatitude :49.402715, 
    positionLongitude :7.445082}
]
});
var json = eventsViewModel.data().toJSON();
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

var events = ko.observableArray(eventsViewModel.data().toJSON());

ko.applyBindings(eventsViewModel,document.getElementById("event-view"));
```

A JSbin, which shows that the log is empty: http://jsbin.com/unEPAwAn/12/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `eventsViewModel.read();` (even if the data is bound locally) before you can access the data using `eventsViewModel.data();`

Comment: If I use JSON.parse on the JSON string in this example, i get this [object Object] before every object inside {} in the array, do you know what that means?

Comment: @amaik I'm guessing you use Internet Explorer and you're talking about the formatting when using console.log()? There is no additional object, it's just the data type of the property being logged.